# Claims Not Being Cleared on Logout

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core

I am using asp.net core api 2.2 and I am using token authentication.

I generate the tokens like this

```
 Claim[] claims = new[] {
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, employee.Id),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat,new DateTimeOffset(now).ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString()),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, allRoles)
                    // TODO: add additional claims here
                };

            var tokenExpirationMins = configuration.GetValue<int>("Auth:Jwt:TokenExpirationInMinutes");
            SymmetricSecurityKey issuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["Auth:Jwt:Key"]));

            JwtSecurityToken token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    issuer: configuration["Auth:Jwt:Issuer"],
                    audience: configuration["Auth:Jwt:Audience"],
                    claims: claims,
                    notBefore: now,
                    expires: now.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(tokenExpirationMins)),
                    signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(
                        issuerSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
                );
            string encodedToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
```

I store the response data in LocalStorage and when I do an ajax request I send the "Bearer Access Token" to the server and then the built in Asp.net Identity / Core take care of authenticating it via the Authorize tags.

In the controller I have something like this

```
  [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet("GetItems")]
        public IActionResult GetItems()
        {
             var isMember = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier) != null;
            return OK();
        }
```

Now this method is used by logged in users and logged out users. Basically the code is all the same except if they are a "member" they see a bit more data.

Now what I noticed is that when a "member" would login and go to this area and gets the "Items" back with all the fields shown and then logout and go back to that page the line of code that checks if they got a Claim will still be populated.

```
var isMember = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier) != null;
```

If I where to refresh the page and go back to it then this would be null. For whatever reason it still holding onto the claims.

This is leading to them see all fields when they should only be seeing a reduced amount of fields as they logged out.

Do I have to clear something else on logout?

Comment: How do you put your JWT into your API call to `GetItems`? Do you clear your JWT from `localStorage` on logout?

Comment: I am using Axios for my Ajax Requests and I add on each request to the header the Bearer Token (axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']) and send it along. When I logout I delete the token from the LocalStorage. Maybe the one loaded into my Axios instance is still kicking around let me check

Comment: Yes. Axios might have it in its memory and you might need to log out from Axios too.